# Why put something in the middle of the pan would prevent soup coming out during cooking?

Tags: thermodynamics

I see a website which teach people to put something on top of the pot during cooking soup to prevent the soup coming out during cooking. What is the physical theory behind that?

[image]

Comment: See this post for answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31029/