# Stopping overflow of boiling milk

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, surface-tension, convection

We all know that milk overflows from the container when boiled.
The reason is air trapped under the skin of the milk, can't escape and hence, pushes the skin upwards until it overflows.

My mother uses a trick to stop the overflow of milk. She puts a ladle on a diameter of the container.
Here are two pictures :

[image]

[image]

What is the reason that the milk doesn't flow over anymore? Is there a gap created on the places where the milk comes in contact with the ladle from which the air escapes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a wooden spoon be used to prevent water from over boiling?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31029/)

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks a lot. That link answered my question. As a sidenote, in your answer in this link, you predicted that metal spoons may not work according to the second mechanism. My images are an example that they do work.